# can I create a summary report with count and percentage?

Tags: r, statistics

I am generating descriptive statistics - I'd like to know how to use R to get percentages. I'm currently converting a numeric to a factor variable and then using summary. This gives me the count, but how to I get R to calculate the percentage? It's probably obvious that I am new to R and will never be an expert. THANKS.

EEB$PBDplanet_import<-as.factor(EEB$PBDplanet_import)
summary(EEB)

My dataset is called EEB. I have columns in excel with names (PBDplanet_import) is a name of the column. I need a code that does mean and %. Right now summary just gives me count.

Thanks!
Erin

Answer (score 1):

`proportions(table(EEB$PBDplanet_import))*100`. If you need detailed summary statistics, `collapse::descr(EBB)` or `DescTools::PercTable(EEB$PBDplanet_import)`.